# ArUco on visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, integration, aruco

opencv2.4.10 was installed on my machine. And it integrates vs2013. Now, I want to create AR app using ArUco and vs2013.

I download ArUco 1.2.4 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/files/). And I create a console application on vs2013. I do below steps :

1.Menu Project ---- $ProjectName Properties

2. Choose Configuration Manager... and add x64 platform
3. At configuration field, choose release configuration

   3.1. At Configuration Properties ---- C/C++ ---- Additional Include Directories,  ..\aruco_msvc\include

   3.2. At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional Library Directories,  ..\aruco_msvc\lib

   3.3 At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional dependencies ---- add dependence libraries

aruco124.dll

tbb.dll

(there are some opencvxxx241.dll but I don't add them. Because I added opencvxxx2410.dll before.)

3.4. Add ..\aruco_msvc\bin to System Environment Path

3.5. Restart Visual studio.

Then, I run my project using release mode, it says that `cannot open input file aruco124.dll`

**EDIT !!!**

I use only aruco_msvc folder from taken [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/files/1.2.4/) these steps. I think that I don't need aruco1.2.4 folder. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I change step 3.3, and it works.

3.3 At Configuration Properties ---- Linker ---- Additional dependencies ---- add dependence libraries

aruco124.lib