# error with detect function in aruco library

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, aruco

I am trying for the first time with aruco library. So for installation i have followed this link [ArUco on visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543484/aruco-on-visual-studio-2013).

```
int main()
{
Mat inputImage;
inputImage = imread("D://singlemarkersoriginal.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

//cv::aruco::Dictionary dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250);
MarkerDetector MDetector;
vector<Marker> Markers;
MDetector.detect(inputImage, Markers); // error in this link of code.
//for each marker, draw info and its boundaries in the image
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Markers.size(); i++)
{
    cout << Markers[i] << endl;
    Markers[i].draw(inputImage, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
}
cv::imshow("in", inputImage);
cv::waitKey(0);//wait for key to be pressed
}
```

When I execute the code it gives the error with the line `MDetector.detect` and I even get error with the getPredefinedDictionary. Is there some additional setup I have to do use the dictionary lib functions.

The input image is [image]

all I want to do is detect the QR codes and find the pose and orientation

Comment: So you get an error... *What* error? A build error? A runtime error or crash? Unexpected data? Please elaborate.

Comment: I get break point : Unhandled exception at 0x524639A5 (aruco124.dll) in aruco_opencv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Comment: What is `MarkerDetector`? I assume it is a custom class wrapping [aruco functions](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html) from OpenCV? BTW these are not QR codes, but Aruco markers..

Comment: the issue was with the linking of the dictionary. it got solved.